# Restricting closed leads from view, global search by owners of the lead

Tags: security, leads

Is there a way I can restrict owners of lead to be able to search closed lead through global search within salesforce. So basically i want to restrict them to view their own closed leads.

We have OWD for Lead set to private and at this time they can search for closed leads through global search.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done at user level but it can be done at profile level by disabling View and Edit Converted Leads see [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_view_converted.htm) you can hide converted leads totally or it will be visible, not possible to control only for global search

Comment: Hi Avijit Thanks.. It has to be done at profile level itself. however, This permission is already disabled.  Moreover, we do not use converted feature. We simply close a lead for some custom process.